# Signature issue with FFTW and Wisdom

Tags: c, fftw

I use FFTW 3.3.8 on Centos 7 Linux target.

**In a first test**, I use FFTW to perform some calculations, results are fine and I use `fftw_export_wisdom_to_filename` to save plans.

**In a second test**, identical to the first test, I've just added a call to `fftw_import_wisdom_from_filename` and the attribute `FFTW_WISDOM` to the plan's calculation and it also works fine.

The trouble occurs when I use `fftw-wisdom-to-conf` on the wisdom file, compile the generated output, and add it to the test binary (binary size is reduced in this case, that is interesting for me).

In this case, the import wisdom function returns "0" due to the wrong signature. The 4 first md5 values in the wisdom file are incorrect (different from the expected ones).

If I patch those values in the wisdom file, all works fine, the import is ok and also FFTW results. No gcc optimization option is activated,

I do not use multi-thread, my configuration looks very simple, do you have any idea that could explain this behavior?

The command used to generate the FFTW library is the following : `./configure CC=gcc CFLAGS="-g" --with-slow-timer --disable-threads --disable-fortran --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/lvcugen/workspace/workspace_ext6/GR712/TMP_FFTW/INSTALL_LINUX`

The content of the `test_fftw_wisdom.c` file used to perform this test and compiled from the `fftw`install directory is the following :

```
/*
 * P.SERAUD : FFTW Wisdom test (define MODE_USE to generate wisdom load binary, default binary generate wisdom
 *
 * Gen wisdom build command : gcc -u main -o0 -g test_fftw_wisdom.c -I ./include -L ./lib -lfftw3 -lm -lc -o test_fftw_gen_wisdom
 * Use wisdom build command : gcc -u main -o0 -g -DMODE_USE test_fftw_wisdom.c conf_wisdom.o -I ./include -L ./lib -lfftw3 -lm -lc -o test_fftw_use_wisdom
 *
 * conf_wisdom file generated by : ./bin/fftw-wisdom-to-conf < wisdom.txt
 *
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "fftw3.h"


/* in : input image 
 * reOut : real part (output)
 * imOut : imaginary part (output)
 * largeur : largeur des images d'entrée et de sortie
 * hauteur : idem
 */
void fourierForward(const double* in,
                    double* reOut,
                    double* imOut,
                    unsigned int largeur,
                    unsigned int hauteur)
{

/* The data is an array of type 'fftw_complex', which is by default a
   'double[2]' composed of the real ('in[i][0]') and imaginary ('in[i][1]') 
     parts of a complex number.
     */

   fftw_complex* spatial_repr;
   fftw_complex* frequency_repr;
   unsigned int i;
   fftw_plan plan;
   fftw_plan plan2;
     int resWisdom=0;

     spatial_repr= fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*largeur*hauteur);
   frequency_repr= fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*largeur*hauteur);

     fftw_set_timelimit(FFTW_NO_TIMELIMIT);

   /* Use Wisdom mode called when MODE_USE is set  */
#ifdef MODE_USE
     printf ("Importing Wisdom %d\n",0);
     resWisdom = fftw_import_wisdom_from_filename("wisdom.txt");

     printf ("Import result %d\n",resWisdom);

     if(resWisdom == 0)
         return;
#endif

   printf("Launching fftw_plan_dft_2d FORWARD with %d / %d\n",largeur, hauteur);
     /*on calcule le plan d'exécution*/
#ifdef MODE_USE
   plan=fftw_plan_dft_2d(hauteur, largeur, spatial_repr, frequency_repr, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_WISDOM_ONLY | FFTW_ESTIMATE);
#else
   plan=fftw_plan_dft_2d(hauteur, largeur, spatial_repr, frequency_repr, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
#endif

     if (plan == NULL)
        { 
    printf("NULL plan generated by fftw_plan_dft_2d with %d / %d !!!\n",largeur, hauteur);
        return;
        }

   /*On remplit la structure qui sera utilisée par fftw*/
   for(i=0;i<largeur*hauteur;i++)
   {
          spatial_repr[i][0] = in[i]; /* real part */
      spatial_repr[i][1] =  0.0;  /* imaginary part */
      frequency_repr[i][0] =  0.0;  /* real part */
      frequency_repr[i][1] =  0.0;  /* imaginary part */
   }

     printf("Executing fftw_execute with %d / %d\n\n",largeur, hauteur);

   /*on effectue la transformée de Fourier*/
   fftw_execute(plan);


   /*on retranscrit le résultat en 2 images, l'une représentant la partie réelle, l'autre
     la partie imaginaire*/
   for(i=0;i<largeur*hauteur;i++)
      {
          reOut[i]=frequency_repr[i][0];
          imOut[i]=frequency_repr[i][1];
                    printf("%d : in (%lf) / reOut (%lf) / imOut (%lf) \n",i, in[i],reOut[i],imOut[i]);
            }

   printf("Launching fftw_plan_dft_2d BACKWARD with %d / %d\n",largeur, hauteur);
#ifdef MODE_USE
   plan2=fftw_plan_dft_2d(hauteur, largeur, spatial_repr, frequency_repr, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_WISDOM_ONLY | FFTW_ESTIMATE);
#else
   plan2=fftw_plan_dft_2d(hauteur, largeur, spatial_repr, frequency_repr, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
#endif

     if (plan2 == NULL)
        { 
    printf("NULL plan generated by fftw_plan_dft_2d with %d / %d !!!\n",largeur, hauteur);
        return;
        }

   /*On remplit la structure qui sera utilisée par fftw*/
   for(i=0;i<largeur*hauteur;i++)
   {
     spatial_repr[i][0] = reOut[i]; /* real part */
     spatial_repr[i][1] = imOut[i]; /* imaginary part */
     frequency_repr[i][0] =  0.0;  /* real part */
     frequency_repr[i][1] =  0.0;  /* imaginary part */
   }

     printf("Executing fftw_execute with %d / %d\n\n",largeur, hauteur);
   /*on effectue la transformée de Fourier*/
   fftw_execute(plan2);

   /*on retrouve la matrice d'origine dans la partie réelle en la divisant par "largeur * hauteur" */ 
   for(i=0;i<largeur*hauteur;i++)
      {
          reOut[i]=frequency_repr[i][0] /(largeur*hauteur);
          imOut[i]=frequency_repr[i][1];
                    printf("%d : in (%lf) / reOut (%lf) / imOut (%lf) \n",i, in[i],reOut[i],imOut[i]);
            }

#ifndef MODE_USE
     resWisdom = fftw_export_wisdom_to_filename("wisdom.txt"); 
     printf ("Wisdom export res = %d\n", resWisdom);
#endif

   /*on détruit les objets*/
   fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
   fftw_destroy_plan(plan2);
   fftw_free(spatial_repr);
   fftw_free(frequency_repr);

}

int main(void) 
{
        printf("Starting !!!!\n");

        double in [8][8] =    {{0.0, 0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0,  70.0,  80.0,  90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0,  90.0, 100.0, 110.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 110.0, 120.0, 130.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 130.0, 140.0, 150.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}};

        double reOut [8][8] = {{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}};

        double imOut [8][8] = {{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}};

        fourierForward(&in[0][0], &reOut[0][0], &imOut[0][0], 8, 8);

        return 0;
}
```

The `conf_wisdom.o` object file included in the `test_fftw_use_wisdom`executable is the result of the compilation of `conf_wisdom.c` source file through `gcc -c conf_wisdom.c`. The content of this source file is the following :

```
/* Automatically generated by fftw-wisdom-to-conf from fftw 3.3.8.
   DO NOT EDIT!  (Unless you really, really want to.  Then it's okay.) */
void fftw_configure_planner(void *plnr)
{
    struct solvtab_s { void (*reg)(void *); const char *reg_nam; };
    extern void fftw_solvtab_exec(const struct solvtab_s s[], void *);

#define DECLARE(name) extern void name(void *);
#define STRINGIZEx(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZEx(x)
#define SOLVTAB(s) { s, STRINGIZE(s) },
#define DO(X) \
    X(fftw_codelet_n1_8)\
    X(fftw_dft_rank_geq2_register)\
    /* end DO(X) */

    DO(DECLARE)

    const struct solvtab_s s[] = {
        DO(SOLVTAB)
        { 0, 0 }
    };

    fftw_solvtab_exec(s, plnr);
}
```

The content of the wisdom.txt file produced by the call to the function `fftw_export_wisdom_to_filename` is the following :

```
(fftw-3.3.8 fftw_wisdom #x4be12fff #x7b2df9b2 #xa5975329 #x385b0041
  (fftw_codelet_n1_8 0 #x31bff #x31bff #x0 #x2874cdd9 #x63ab3b26 #xcb8c1374 #xedc69a82)
  (fftw_codelet_n1_8 0 #x31bff #x31bff #x0 #x4e583e34 #x14aedc27 #x54a2fad7 #xd124b261)
  (fftw_dft_rank_geq2_register 0 #x31bff #x31bff #x0 #xcd87e2bd #x8b6dd8ee #x2d70ed77 #xd20ea4af)
  (fftw_codelet_n1_8 0 #x31bff #x31bff #x0 #xece23a64 #x64207145 #x3f794c2c #x32ef2fbf)
  (fftw_dft_rank_geq2_register 0 #x31bff #x31bff #x0 #xd416e586 #xdc5a4e14 #x2b04907f #x69b22bd8)
  (fftw_codelet_n1_8 0 #x31bff #x31bff #x0 #x155aa639 #x5f99241d #x6351b1a0 #xc7ccb78d)
)
```

The wrong md5 values checked unsucessfully are **#x4be12fff #x7b2df9b2 #xa5975329 #x385b0041**. if thoses values are replaced with the expected ones, all work fine.

Also, when the full content of the library is included in the `test_fftw_use_wisdom` binary (conf_wisdom.o file is not used), it works fine too.

In fact the problem is located in the function `signature_of_configuration` which is used by both import and export functions. When the `conf_wisdom.o`is included, the `planner` content (solver list associated to `nslvdesc` and `slvdescsiz`) is reduced regarding full list and the associated md5 values are necessary different.

The workaround of this problem is to **export the wisdom 2 times** :
 1. The wisdom is generated with a full library configuration.
 2. The wisdom is re-generated with the same source code but with the reduced library configuration (just add the result of the compilation of the output of the fftw-wisdom-to-conf tool to the link).
 3. This last wisdom is able to be imported successfully in the reduced library configuration.

Comment: Provide a [mre].

Comment: Hello,
I've added the source code I use to perform this test.I hope that this will be enough and clear.

Comment: I built FFTW and your source code and they appear to run okay. Using `./bin/fftw-wisdom-to-conf < wisdom.txt` generates only a small amount of C code, and I expect it can be different on different platforms—I am running on macOS 10.14.6 on a MacBookPro13,2. You may need to show your `wisdom.txt`. Also, the instructions in your source file show `./bin/fftw-wisdom-to-conf <wisdom.txt`, but this does not show how you get the output of that into something that becomes, apparently, `conf_wisdom.o`. A full [mre] is complete, showing all commands needed.

Comment: I've added the missing informations. My test is very basic regarding wisdom function.

Comment: I've also completed the test regarding the location of the error.

Comment: (a) Your `wisdom.txt` and `wisdom.c` are identical to mine. (b) I have to retract my statement that it is running okay for me. The import fails. Maybe I was not including `wisdom.c` in the build previously? (c) When the import is done immediately after the export, in the same program execution, it reports success. (d) If `wisdom.c` is either included in both the import and export versions of the program or excluded from both, then the wisdom import succeeds. So I suggest you proceed by including it in both.

Comment: I realize that is a shortcoming—you cannot make `wisdom.c` without an initial execution of a program that creates the wisdom, and that initial program must be built without `wisdom.c`. But it should be a reasonable workaround, and you can report the issue to the FFTW folks for future development.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. 
I've reported the issue to fftw@fftw.org. I've patched planner.c @ line 848 to remove the first part of MD5 signature check and it works fine. Due to embedded constraints, my purpose is to limit the size of the FFTW library to the part needed by my calculations. That's why wisdom is very useful. I cannot execute a program that create the wisdom because this program contains the full FFTW library.

Answer (score 0):

Testing shows that when the `wisdom.c` generated from the wisdom data is included in both the importing program and the exporting program, the import works. It also works when `wisdom.c` is not included in either program. When it is included in the importing program but not the exporting program, it fails.

Thus, a workaround is to build the export program without `wisdom.c`, export the wisdom, generate `wisdom.c`, rebuild the export program with `wisdom.c`, export the wisdom anew, and then build the import program with `wisdom.c`.

This appears to be a defect in FFTW, possibly in the design of the checksum checking.

Comment: I just discover your answer after my exchanges with Matteo Frigo regarding this problem and the completion of my question with its suggested workaround which works fine. It is identical to your solution, I've suggested that at least this specific and not evident process should be precised in the documentation of fftw-wisdom_to-conf tool.